# RDS Snapshot mysql restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I am in the process of restoring a database from RDS using a recent snapshot. When I restore and RDS mysql snapshot will this affect the currently running instance of the RDS database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It won't, the restore happens in a new DB Instance.

> You cannot restore from a DB snapshot to an existing DB instance; a
>   new DB instance is created when you restore.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

But afterwards you can rename the current instance to ...-old, this also renames the db url. After the url is also changed, you have to rename the restored db to the befored used name, wait until the url of the db changes. Then you have to restart your services, and they will connect to the restored db.